# How to express delimited continuations with pure functions only?

Tags: haskell, continuations, continuation-passing, delimited-continuations

I worked through Oleg's [tutorial](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/Haskell-tutorial.pdf) of delimited continuations:

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont{runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}

instance Monad (Cont r) where
  return x = Cont (\k -> k x)
  Cont m >>= f = Cont (\k -> m (\v -> runCont (f v) k))

runC :: Cont r r -> r
runC m = runCont m id

reset :: Cont a a -> Cont r a
reset = return . runC

shift :: ((a -> r) -> Cont r r) -> Cont r a
shift f = Cont (runC . f)

liftM2 (-)
  (reset
    (liftM2 (+) (return 3)
      (shift (\k -> return (5*2))))) -- drop the continuation
        (return 1) -- 9
```

Since continuations are basically functions and `reset`/`shift` are not even part of the monad api, I wonder how to implement delimited continuations without the `newtype` and monad machinery.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
reset :: Cont a a -> Cont r a -- becomes
reset :: ((a -> a) -> a) -> (a -> r) -> r
reset k f = f $ k id

shift :: ((a -> r) -> Cont r r) -> Cont r a -- becomes
shift :: ((a -> r) -> (r -> r) -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r
shift f k = f k id
```

I am pretty sure this is plain wrong and if it's not I don't know how to apply the operators correctly:

```
(1-) (reset ((3+) (shift (\k -> 5*2)))) -- yields

• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num ((a -> a) -> a)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    t1 :: forall a r.
          (Num ((a -> a) -> a), Num ((a -> r) -> r)) =>
          (a -> r) -> r
```

Comment: I don't know what character `∗` (U+2217) is, but it's certainly not an asterisk, `*` (U+002A). The error probably tells you something like this, which is why you should put it in your question, instead of just saying 'compile error'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep going!

```
import Prelude hiding (return)

-- reset :: Cont a a -> Cont r a
reset :: ((a -> a) -> a) -> (a -> r) -> r
reset k f = f $ k id

-- shift :: ((a -> r) -> Cont r r) -> Cont r a
shift :: ((a -> r) -> (r -> r) -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r
shift f k = f k id

-- return :: a -> Cont r a
return :: a -> (a -> r) -> r
return a k = k a

-- liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Cont r a -> Cont r b -> Cont r c
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a -> r) -> r) -> ((b -> r) -> r) -> (c -> r) -> r
liftM2 f ma mb k = ma $ \a -> mb $ \b -> k (f a b)

example :: Num a => (a -> r) -> r
example = liftM2 (-) (reset (liftM2 (+) (return 3) (shift (\k -> return (5*2))))) (return 1)
```

One issue with `(1-) (reset ((3+) (shift (\k -> 5*2))))` is that you're replacing `Cont`'s `return` with `id`, when it's actually `flip id`:

```
λ :t shift (\k -> 5*2)
shift (\k -> 5*2) :: Num ((r -> r) -> r) => (a -> r) -> r
λ :t shift (\k -> ($ 5*2))
shift (\k -> ($ 5*2)) :: Num r => (a -> r) -> r
```

Usually, when ghci says "we need to be able to treat functions as numbers for this code to work", that means you've made a mistake somewhere :)

Comment: Of course, I still need `return` and a binary lift operation, even if both are not part of the monad class anymore. Thank you so much!